# Group JSON by country and output a list of the states sorted alphabetically

Tags: javascript, json, sorting, recursion, nested

I would like to group the input JSON by country and output a list of countries sorted alphabetically and list the names of the states alphabetically in each country.

```
//I would like the expected output in alphabetically sorted order in country    
// and if the country has more than 1 state, the state should be in sorted order as follows:

var res=[
{
  "country": "A", "state": "aa",
  "country": "A", "state: "ca",
  "country": "B", "state": "aa",
  "country": "B", "state": "ca",
  "country": "C", "state": "bb",
  "country": "C", "state": "cb"
 }
]   

// GIVEN input variable in JSON format
 var input = [{
    "country": "A",
    "state": "aa",
    "information": [
        {
            "country": "B",
            "state": "aa"
        },
        {
            "country": "C",
            "state": "bb"
        },
        {
            "country": "C",
            "state": "cb",
            "information": [
                {
                    "country": "A",
                    "state": "ca"
                },
                {
                    "country": "B",
                    "state": "ca"
                }
            ]
        } 
      ]
}];
```

// I have tried the following recursive function because it seems that there might be more than 1 nested function for information. I tried to console.log the expected output, but it does not output the result which I would like:

```
var res=[];
console.log(compare(input,0));

function compare (input, n) { 
  if(!input[0].information) return res;
  for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    res.push(
      { 
        country: input[i].country,
        state: input[i].state
      }
    )  
  }
  console.log("res"+res[0]);
  return compare(input[0].information, input[0].information.length)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `res` is an array with one object with multiple keys using the same names(`country` and `state`), which isn't possible, so I'm going to assume you meant multiple objects but you forgot the `{` and `}`s, (and assuming that's the case, ) then one solution would be the following:

```
var input = [
    {
        "country": "A",
        "state": "aa",
        "information": [
            {
                "country": "B",
                "state": "aa"
            },
            {
            "country": "C",
            "state": "bb"
            },
            {
                "country": "C",
                "state": "cb",
                "information": [
                    {
                        "country": "A",
                        "state": "ca"
                    },
                    {
                        "country": "B",
                        "state": "ca"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];

var output = [];

function flattenInformation (countries) {
    var newCountries = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
        var country = countries[i];

        if (country.hasOwnProperty('information')) {
            var information = country['information'];
            newCountries = newCountries.concat(flattenInformation(information));
            delete country['information'];
        }

        newCountries.push(country);
    }

    return newCountries;
}

output = flattenInformation(input);
output.sort(function(a, b) {
    if(a.country < b.country) return -1;
    if(a.country > b.country) return 1;
    if(a.state < b.state) return -1;
    if(a.state > b.state) return 1;
    return 0;
});

console.log(output);//[{"country":"A","state":"aa"},{"country":"A","state":"ca"},{"country":"B","state":"aa"},{"country":"B","state":"ca"},{"country":"C","state":"bb"},{"country":"C","state":"cb"}]
```

Comment: Thanks!! It's brilliant. The output array is correct, however the above sort function doesn't work correctly, I'm still working on it. Please let me know if you knew any other way to sort it. Thanks!

Comment: @user21 I want to help you, but I'm afraid I don't understand the problem. In the code I have provided, there is a sorting function that is being applied to `output`. And then there is a `console.log` for `output`, and a comment with the output I got when I executed it. Are you saying that you do not get the same output as me, or are you saying that I have misunderstood how it should be sorted? (If so, please specify the requirements)

Comment: Sorry I must have type wrongly for the key a in sublime. Your code for the sorting function works well. Thank you so much for your help!